# MSSQL Server Необязательные параметры в функции

Tags: sql-server

Имею некую функцию, которая возвращает табличное значение. В ней есть несколько необязательных параметров. Проблема в том, что при вызове функции (в скуль студии) без указания параметров получаю пустую выборку, а так быть не должно.
Чувствую, что неверно заданы условия в where. Но как только не изголялся, работать не хочет как должно.

Функция выглядит так:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.GetPeople(@m_id       INT,
                             @sex        INT = -1,
                             @country_id INT = -1,
                             @city_id    INT = -1)
RETURNS @ReturnTable TABLE(-- тут поля
AS
     BEGIN

         INSERT INTO @ReturnTable(-- тут поля
                FROM users
                WHERE @sex > 0
                      AND sex = @sex
                      AND @country_id > 0
                          AND sex = @sex
                      AND @country_id > 0
                          AND sex = @sex;
         RETURN;
     END;
```

Вызываю соответственно

```
SELECT * FROM GetPeople (1234567,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT)
```

Comment: а что должно возвращаться в случае параметров по умолчанию?

Comment: у вас если условия всегда ложные, чего вы хотите? передав `-1` вы ведь не получите `@sex > 0`

Comment: вам вероятно надо что то вида `((@sex = -1) OR (sex = @sex)) ... AND ..`

Comment: мне нужно чтобы в where учитывалось sex=@sex только если параметр @sex отличен от значения по умолчанию, т.е. задан. а если sex не задан, то и не использовать его в where

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE(@country_id = -1
      AND country_id > 0
      OR @country_id > -1
         AND country_id = @country_id)
     AND (@city_id = -1
          AND city_id > 0
          OR @city_id > -1
             AND city_id = @city_id)
     AND (@sex = -1
          AND sex >= 0
          OR sex > -1
             AND sex = @sex)
```

вроде подошло

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, через `CASE` проще и читабельней:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.GetPeople(@m_id       INT,
                             @sex        INT = -1,
                             @country_id INT = -1,
                             @city_id    INT = -1)
RETURNS @ReturnTable TABLE(-- тут поля
AS
     BEGIN

         INSERT INTO @ReturnTable(-- тут поля
                FROM users
                WHERE sex = CASE
                                WHEN @sex = -1
                                THEN sex
                                ELSE @sex
                            END
                      AND country_id = CASE
                                           WHEN @country_id = -1
                                           THEN country_id
                                           ELSE @country_id
                                       END
                      AND city_id = CASE
                                        WHEN @city_id = -1
                                        THEN city_id
                                        ELSE @city_id
                                    END;
         RETURN;
     END;
```